# Laravel cannot display a selected product details

Tags: laravel, object, view, product

maybe someone can help me. I have done a product list from my database. It shows product image, title, content, price
When I select on one of the products, it opens in the new window. And I cant see any product details (no image, no title, no content) , just empty page.
See all attachments:
my **BrackController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\file;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class BracController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('insertBrac');
    }

    public function showBrac()
    {
        $user=file::all();
        return view('apyrankes', compact('user'));
    }

    public function view_brac()
{
    $object = \DB::table('braclets')->where('BrackID' , request('brackId'))->first();
    return view('view_object', array('user' => $object));
}

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        {
        $user = new file;

        $user->Title= Input::get('title');
        $user->Content= Input::get('content');
        $user->Price= Input::get('price');
        if (Input::hasFile('image'))
            {
                $file=Input::file('image');
                $file->move(public_path(). '/uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());

                $user->Image = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            }

        $user->save();

        return redirect( "insertBrac" );

     }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

My product list: 
**apyrankes.blade.php**

```
<div class="header">
    @include('header')
</header>
<body>
        <div class="content-products">
                    @foreach($user as $users)
                    <div id="myDiv">
                        <div class="products">
                            <img src="{{ $users->Image}}" alt="{{ $users->Title}}" width="200px" height="200px"><br>
                            {{ $users->Title}}<br>
                            {{ $users->Content}}<br>
                            {{ $users->Price}}€<br>
                            <a href="view_object?product={{ $users->BrackID }}">Plačiau</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
        </div>


</body>
```

And when I select one of the product from product list on apyrankes.blade.php 
it opens in view_object.blade.php , but I cannot see there any details of the select product, just empty page:
My **view_object.blade.php**

```
<div class="header">
    @include('header')
</header>
        <body>
            <Br>
            <br>
            <Br>
            <div class="content-products">
                <div id="myDiv">
                    <div class="products">
                        @if($user)
                        <img src="{{ $user->Image}}" alt="{{ $user->Title}}" width="200px" height="200px"><br>
                        {{ $user->Title}}<br>
                        {{ $user->Content}}<br>
                        {{ $user->Price}}€<br>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>         
        </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did

```
<a href="view_object?product={{ $users->BrackID }}">Plačiau</a></div>
```

The name of the variable you need to fetch is **product**

```
$object = \DB::table('braclets')->where('BrackID' , request('product'))->first();
```